# Why ansible keeps recreating docker containers with state "started"

Tags: docker, ansible

I have a docker container managed by Ansible. Every time I start the container with Ansible it is recreated instead of just started.

Here are the Ansible commands I use to stop/start the container:

```
ansible-playbook <playbook> -i <inventory> --extra-vars "state=stopped"
ansible-playbook <playbook> -i <inventory> --extra-vars "state=started"
```

Here's the Ansible taks I use to manage container. The only thing that changes between "stop" and "start" command is {{ state }}.

```
- docker:
    name: "{{ postgres_container_name }}"
    image: "{{ postgres_image_name }}"
    state: "{{ state }}"
    ports:
      - "{{ postgres_host_port }}:{{ postgres_guest_port }}"
    env:
      POSTGRES_USER: "{{ postgres_user }}"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "{{ postgres_password }}"
      POSTGRES_DB: "{{ postgres_db }}"
```

When I start, stop and start the container I get the following verbose output from Ansible command:

```
changed: [127.0.0.1] => {"ansible_facts": {"docker_containers": [{"Id": "ab1c0f6cc30de33aba31ce93671267783ba08a1294df40556870e66e8bf77b6d", "Warnings": null}]}, "changed": true, "containers": [{"Id": "ab1c0f6cc30de33aba31ce93671267783ba08a1294df40556870e66e8bf77b6d", "Warnings": null}], "msg": "removed 1 container, started 1 container, created 1 container.", "reload_reasons": null, "summary": {"created": 1, "killed": 0, "pulled": 0, "removed": 1, "restarted": 0, "started": 1, "stopped": 0}}
```

It states that the container changed, was removed, created and started.

Could you tell me why Ansible sees my container as changed and recreates it instead of starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible's docker module will first remove any stopped containers with the same name when you use it with the state of `started`.

The [module docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html) don't really make it all that clear but there is a comment explaining this in the source code in the [`started` function](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/cloud/docker/docker.py#L1560).

Comment: It looks that there is no possibility to start stopped containers without recreating them. All of states: started, reloaded and restarted remove a container if it's stopped. As a consequence it's not possible to run command working like: "docker start {{ container_name }} with Ansible.  I should create a data container in order to avoid losing data every time I start containers. Am I right?

Comment: Not necessarily a data container, this pattern has been replaced by [using volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/).